# How To Use CCSlider in Cocos2d v3.2.1?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am new in cocos2d iPhone development.My question is how to use CCSlider in Cocos2d v3.2.
CCSlider has only two parameter (background spriteFrame and HandleImage).How we can change the colour/Image of slider when we change the Thumb position.How we can differentiate between empty and full bars, how to make progress of filling?

Suppose I want to use to colour like red(Empty) and green(Fill)/two different images for slider.By default the slider colour is red means the slider value is 0.0f(Empty).if I increase the value of slider then the slider colour will change to green(Fill) from position 0.0 to current thumb position.Please help me.sorry for my question i am very week in english

Thank You.

Comment: look at the superclass CCControl which has most of the functionality: http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCControl.html

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Can you just explain with example? Please..

Comment: can anybody help me? I am just stuck that point.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a progress bar with some kind of thumb showing current position... CCSlider is meant for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i use CCSlider for volume control. This code is in the **`init`** method of a GameOptions menu class:

```
CCSpriteFrame *frRuler = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"slider_track.png"];
CCSpriteFrame *frKnob  = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"slider_knob.png"];
_mainGain = [[CCSlider alloc] initWithBackground:frRuler andHandleImage:frKnob];
[self addChild:_mainGain];
[_mainGain setTarget:self selector:@selector(onMainGainChange:)];
_mainGain.anchorPoint  = ccp(.5, .5);
_mainGain.visible      = YES;
_mainGain.positionType = CCPositionTypePoints;
_mainGain.position     = ccp(kScreenWidth / 2, kScreenHeight / 2 - 55);
_mainGain.continuous   = YES;
_mainGain.sliderValue  = _battlesSettings.audio.masterVolumeGain; // initial
```

with the following method to receive the slider control 'slide' events :

```
- (void)onMainGainChange:(id)sender {
    CCSlider *sl = (CCSlider *) sender;
    _battlesSettings.audio.masterVolumeGain = sl.sliderValue;
    _isSettingsDirty = YES;
}
```

Comment: I did the same but how we can differentiate between empty and full bars, how to make progress of filling?

Comment: Instead of giving me your solution to a problem (CCSlider) why dont you tell us what you are to accomplish ?  update the question. Your above question makes no sense to me in the context of CCSlider : a control to manipulate and change a setting progressively, by using touch on the `knob` and sliding it on the `slider`, changing the value progressively from 0.f to 1.f .

Comment: i want to use to colour like red and green/two different images for slider.By default the slider colour is red means the slider value is 0.0f.if i increase the value of slider then the slider colour will change to green from position 0.0 to current thumb position.Please help me.sorry for my question i am very week in english.